# I don't understand the behaviour of the break statement in my for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, break

I'm programming a Python exercise task and wondering about the behavior of my code. Im a C and C++ programmer and totally lost here. Can someone tell me why Python does here what it does?

this code reads a table of Names organizet in years, US states and count, how often a child was named after it. It is basicly a Name statistic from USA. The following Code performs correkt:

```
with open("../data/names.csv") as file:
    file.readline() #removes table header
    counter = 0
    splitLine = {}

    for year in file:        
        splitLine = year.strip().split(',')
        
        if int(splitLine[2]) < 1950:
            continue
        if splitLine[1] != "Max":
            continue
        if splitLine[3] != "M":
            continue
        if splitLine[4] != "CA":
            continue
        if int(splitLine[2]) > 2000:
            break
            
        counter += int(splitLine[5])
        print(splitLine)

print(counter)
```

This code produces following output (i shortened the output):
(...) 
['663639', 'Max', '1998', 'M', 'CA', '285'] 
['666069', 'Max', '1999', 'M', 'CA', '296'] 
['668521', 'Max', '2000', 'M', 'CA', '341'] 
6385

Then i tryed to clean up my code and moved the if statement with the break, up:

```
with open("../data/names.csv") as file:
    file.readline() #removes table header
    counter = 0
    splitLine = {}

    for year in file:        
        splitLine = year.strip().split(',')
        
        if int(splitLine[2]) < 1950:
            continue
        if int(splitLine[2]) > 2000:
            break
        if splitLine[1] != "Max":
            continue
        if splitLine[3] != "M":
            continue
        if splitLine[4] != "CA":
            continue
        
        counter += int(splitLine[5])
        print(splitLine)

print(counter)
```

This code produces following output: 
0

In this case, the for-loot seems to perform the same iteration, but does not reach the increment- and print- statements. Why is this? A C Code would perform exactly the same way in both cases.

Comment: This behavior here should be identical to how it is in C/C++. I don't remember there being any differences between Python's and C's `break`/`continue` behavior that would be relevant here.

Comment: It could be connected to the values inside of the CSV-file, which would match against the `if int(splitLine[2]) > 2000:` statement immediately, and thus breaking out of the loop. But because we do not have an example we cannot be sure.

Comment: Note: I suggest using your IDE features to set breakpoints, or otherwise write unit tests for your code. If you assume the loop is the same, then your tests would have passed... https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Also, Python has built-in functions for reading csv files - https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: You should not alter the code as you did. `if int(splitLine[2]) > 2000:` part would never run if `splitLine[1]` is not `"Max"`, `"M"`, or `"CA"`. By changing the position you allow it to `break` when it should not.

Answer (score 1):

#### This is not caused by the language, but by the ordering of your data

```
if int(splitLine[2]) < 1950:
    continue
if int(splitLine[2]) > 2000:
    break;
if splitLine[1] != "Max":
    continue
if splitLine[3] != "M":
    continue
if splitLine[4] != "CA":
    continue
```

As soon as it sees a data >2000, the loop will *end* completely.

Look at your data carefully. I bet you will find in the *upper part of your table*, values with

- year >2000
- but not having the full house of "Max", "M" and "CA"

Your *first* program will *not* terminate on those lines, because they don't have the full house of Max/M/CA (and therefore those lines will cause `continue` to occur).

Your *second* program will test for the year first, and will terminate as soon as it hits one of those lines.

#### In general this is a bad design of filtering

And that is because of exactly the problem you see: you create a filtering system that is *hard to reason about*.

It would be better to write your test like this:

```
if (
    int(splitLine[2]) >= 1950 and
    int(splitLine[2]) <= 2000 and
    splitLine[1] == "Max" and
    splitLine[3] == "M" and
    splitLine[4] == "CA"
):
    counter += int(splitLine[5])
    print(splitLine)
```

#### Advantages of this arrangement

- Much easier to read (and therefore debug)
- Shorter without being uglier
- You could even shorten the two date criteria to just `1950<=splitLine[2]<=2000`

#### Disadvantages

Because you don't terminate the loop as soon as you get to the year 2000 of the Max/M/CAs, you will search through the *whole* of the input and not (on average) *half* of the input (assuming your Max/M/CA search criteria might be any where in the input).

However this approximate doubling of search time is trivial compared to the headache you save from being unconfident about how the search is working.

Answer (score 0):

The break statement simply exits the loop. Here is a simple example of break working as expected.

```
for i in range(0, 4):
    if i == 2:
        break
    else:
        print(i)
print(f"Loop ended with i = {i}")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This answers what was asked... Doesn't solve the problem mentioned in the question

Comment: Agreed, but I wanted to confirm what the behavior of break is in Python as asked in the title.

Comment: I think OP understands that. The question is more about why `int(splitLine[2]) > 2000` condition with the break is being entered...  See "_Why is this_?"